# How to get count of files by their type, recursively

Tags: bash, shell

I'm wondering if there is any convenient way to do this. 
Basically what I'm trying to do is to create a shellscript that would create a writedown of multiple file types.

For example an output could look like this:

> ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64:  $amount
>   ELF 32-bit LSB shared> object, INTEL: $amount
>   ASCII text: $amount

In order to get your text to look somewhat like this you need to:

1. Create a list of files you need to check
2. Get the file names
3. Feed them to the file utility
4. Cut a specific line from the output

So first things first, to get all our files we want to check

```
find $DIR -type f | ls -1
```

which will print the following (obviously an example, results differ based on what is set as $DIR

> mysript.sh
>   game.exe
>   text.txt

Through this we will get to our STDOUT a list of all the FILES in our current directory.
However now what I'm not sure is how to feed these file names 1 by 1 to the file utility to basically get my output.

Biggest issue is, file util can handle only 1 file, not multiple directories etc.

so the only thing i can think of is to do it like this

```
    FILE_AMOUNT=`find $PWD -type f | ls -1 | wc -l`
    while [ "$i" -lt "$FILE_AMOUNT" ] 
    do
         #code here
         $(( i++ ))
         PRINT_TYPE=`file $myfile | cut -d":" -f2`
    done
```

But I'm not sure how to get the files one by one and assign them to the myfile variable so we can cycle loop through them. As you can see, the command above dumps multiple file names and their extensions, however I'm not sure how i can take them 1 by one and assign them to the my file variable. Any ideas?

Or maybe there is far better solution to this altogether?

Comment: See your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891893/any-idea-why-sort-utility-gives-me-incorrect-results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file` command doesn't read from stdin.  So, we need to loop through the files, call `file` on each one of them, and collect the summary in an associative array:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A file_types
while read -r file; do
  type=$(file -b "$file") # -b tells file not to prefix the file name in output
  ((file_types[$type]++))
done < <(find "$PWD" -type f)

# traverse the associative array and print results
for type in "${!file_types[@]}"; do
  printf '%s: %s\n' "$type" "${file_types[$type]}"
done
```

The first loop could be written more efficiently, without the need to call `file` in a subshell, as:

```
while read -r type; do
  ((file_types[$type]++))
done < <(find "$PWD" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file -b)
```

---

For my directory, it gives:

```
VAX COFF executable - version 5424: 1
VAX COFF executable - version 10614: 1
VAX COFF executable not stripped: 5
VAX COFF executable not stripped - version 902: 1
Perl5 module source text, ASCII text: 7
VAX COFF executable: 3
ASCII text: 23
Perl POD document text, UTF-8 Unicode text: 1
empty: 2
Bourne-Again shell script text executable, ASCII text: 2
VAX COFF executable - version 67: 1
a /usr/bin/env ruby script text executable, ASCII text: 1
POSIX shell script text executable, ASCII text: 12
Git index, version 2, 3 entries: 1
a /usr/bin/perl -w script text executable, ASCII text: 12
ASCII text, with very long lines: 2
Vim swap file, version 7.4: 1
```