# Any idea why sort utility gives me incorrect results?

Tags: bash, shell

EDIT:
To be clear, we got our STDOUT from a for loop that goes something like this

```
for (( i=1; i<="$FILE_AMOUNT"; i++ )); do
    MY_FILE=`find $DIR -type f | head -$i | tail -1`
    FILE_TYPE=`file -b "$MY_FILE"
    FILE_TYPE_COUNT=`echo $FILE_TYPE" | sort | uniq -c`
    echo "$FILE_TYPE_COUNT"
done
```

Hence our STDOUT is basically output from file utility printed one by one, instead of it actualling being set of strings we can copy - which is likely the core behind all of the issues

---

---

---

`

So there's a pickle i absolutely can't wrap my head around.

Basically i'm creating a shellscript that will print out various filetypes we have in our directory. It pretty much works, however, for some odd reason when i try to use uniq on my output, it doesnt work. This is my output

```
POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
ASCII text
Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
UTF-8 Unicode text, with overstriking
Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

Seems fairly self-explanatory, however when I use

```
FILE_TYPE_COUNT=`echo "$FILE_TYPE" | sort | uniq -c`
```

this is the result it prints

```
  1 POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
  1 ASCII text
  1 Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
  1 UTF-8 Unicode text, with overstriking
  1 Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

Obviously it should be

```
  1 POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
  1 ASCII text
  2 Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
  1 UTF-8 Unicode text, with overstriking
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Obviously uniq thinks the lines aren't different, but that's what I assume is at fault of sort, because it cant sort my STDOUT. So any clue how to sort the list properly ALPHABETICALlY?

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue, I get the expected "2 Bourne-Again …". Are you sure the content of `$FILE_TYPE` is correct?

Comment: Include the code that sets FILE_TYPE.

Comment: @P.Gerber
added the for loop in the edit, hopefully it's a bit more clear now

Comment: Create complete output, *then* sort and uniq that. Doing this per line makes no sense.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @Cyrus its not much use, since it works with files and directories. However i pasted it and apart from few warnings for quotation marks or to use $() instead of `` it compiled. but i'm not sure what use that is, because as mentioned, you will never get an output there with no directories or files being online

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach seem overly complicated, try this:

```sh
find $DIR -type f -exec file -b -- {} \; | sort | uniq -c
```

If you'r not familiar with `-exec`, it executes the given command, in our case `file -b -- {}`, once per file. The place holder `{}` is replaced with the path to the file currently being processed.

Why you approach doesn't work:

You do this `echo $FILE_TYPE" | sort | uniq -c` within the for loop, `$FILE_TYPE` contains only the file type of one file at that point. You need to move the `sort | uniq -c` out of the loop.

I adjusted your code so it works:

```
declare -a TYPES=()
for (( i=1; i<="$FILE_AMOUNT"; i++ )); do
    MY_FILE=`find a/ -type f | head -$i | tail -1`
    FILE_TYPE=`file -b "$MY_FILE"`
    TYPES+=("$FILE_TYPE") # add type of current file to TYPES array
done

# TYPES now contains the types of all files and we can now count them
printf "%s\n" "${TYPES[@]}" | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: yup does the trick, thank you! :)

though one question, could you explain why it didnt work in my example, or you aren't sure either?

Comment: @Rawrplus adjusted the answer

Comment: You could also simply use the `| sort | uniq -c` after the `done`. In this way, you can print directly from the loop and save some memory and some complication.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are seeing is because you are sorting a set of one item, for every iteration of the loop.

You'd need to sort the whole output of the loop instead.

Your (syntactically fixed) script:

```
for (( i=1; i<="$FILE_AMOUNT"; i++ )); do
    MY_FILE=`find $DIR -type f | head -$i | tail -1`
    FILE_TYPE=`file -b "$MY_FILE"`
    FILE_TYPE_COUNT=`echo "$FILE_TYPE" | sort | uniq -c`
    echo "$FILE_TYPE_COUNT"
done
```

Mofified to work properly:

```
for (( i=1; i<="$FILE_AMOUNT"; i++ )); do
    MY_FILE=`find $DIR -type f | head -$i | tail -1`
    file -b "$MY_FILE"
done | sort | uniq -c
```

Optimised once:

```
for FILE in $(find $DIR -type f); do
    file -b "$FILE"
done | sort | uniq -c
```

Optimised twice (See @P. Gerber's Answer):

```
find $DIR -type f -exec file -b -- {} \; | sort | uniq -c
```

---

Your original script is horrifically inefficient.

Notes on efficiency & operation:

- `${FILE_AMOUNT}` has to be correct to iterate over the whole dataset
- You are running `find`, which returns the whole dataset and then discarding everything that you're not interested in, *every iteration*
- You are running `sort` and `uniq`, on every iteration, on a dataset of size one
- As you are constantly re-computing your dataset, if it changes half way through your script's execution (e.g: file / directory is created / deleted), then your results will become invalid
- Remember that every time you start a new program, you pay a performance penalty - this is exacerbated by the fact that you are continually computing your dataset and then discarding "everything that you don't want"

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other good solutions here, be sure to understand the sorting rule set that you are using.  To inspect your current sorting rule, you can do:

```
echo anything | sort --debug
```

to see your results with annotations. Consider:

```
echo -e "a 2\na1" | sort --debug
sort: using ‘en_US.UTF-8’ sorting rules
a1
__
a 2
___
```

Note that the rule set is sorting with perhaps an unexpected result. If you're looking for a simple byte comparison, then be sure to set `LC_ALL=C` as in:

```
LC_ALL=C sort
```

For example:

```
echo -e "a 2\na1" | LC_ALL=C sort --debug
sort: using simple byte comparison
a 2
___
a1
__
```

The use of `LC_ALL` is important in getting the results you expect. Lastly, run the `locale` command and read the man page to get locale-specific information.